# What does a beginning 'u do when defining a string in python?

Tags: python

I just started learning python a few days ago and I came across the `str.isdecimal()` function. I get an error when I type the following into a python environment:

```
    text="123"
    Print text.isdecimal()
```

The error is: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'.

However, when I type the following:

```
    text=u"123"
    Print text.isdecimal()
```

Then things work out fine and I get "True" in return as expected.

**My question**

What is happening here? Specifically, what is the u doing to the string definition and why wont the isdecimal function work otherwise?

Thank you and sorry for if the question is too elementary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isdecimal` is a method on Unicode strings, but not byte strings.  `u'xxx'` defines a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

It defines the string as the `unicode` type, rather than a `str` type.

```
    type(u'foo')
    <type 'unicode'>
```